# Is it possible to have 2 kernel module linked to the same /dev/device?

Tags: linux, module, kernel, driver, device

I want to simulate an expensive device by a software mockup (we call it (B)) interacting with */dev/device* in place of the real device

Currently a kernel module already exists to manage the real device that is linked to */dev/device*   (we call it (A)).

Is it possible that (A) sends data to /dev/device and that (B) reads this data, prepares a response and sends it back to */dev/device*, and that (A) reads this response ?

If there exists an easier solution to do what I want (i.e. simulate the hardware device with a software mockup) do not hesitate to suggest.

Comment: So is this (B) a mockup or a real device? If I understand correctly, the point is to create a simulation in userspace so It can communicate with Kernel module (A) via *dev/device*?

Comment: Try looking at [umockdev](http://www.piware.de/2013/02/umockdev-record-and-mock-hardware-for-debugging-and-testing/).

Comment: @KBart (B) is a software mockup not a real device, but simulating this device that I don't have. And yes I want to communicate through /dev/device

Comment: @Antoine I will have look to umockdev if it suits my needs.

Comment: @Antoine The mockup is already coded, umockdev seems to need to code it again in Python. This may be a solution but for the long term if no answer to this question.

Comment: @Fabien it is hard to tell without knowing what actually your device/drivers do, but I would take such approach: connect second PC by the original interface (A) uses or route it to any other (UART, USB etc.) On the second PC daemonize you mockup (B) and connect to appropriate dev/interface. As I understand, you want to inspect that device on protocol level, so the underlying interface is of no importance. It would look like: PC1[dummy_client/logger<--dev/device<-->kmodule(A)<-->interface]<----->PC2[interface-->dev/int-->mockup_daemon(B)]

Comment: @KBart thanks for your solution. I will keep it in mind.  However I would prefer using only one PC is possible. This to avoid complexifying the test architecture by having a complete PC simulating a small device. BTW I am investigating hacking directly the (A) kernel module to plug in its code the (B) mockup there, and putting code into #ifdef #endif for tests.

Comment: @Fabien and the goal is to test/debug your kmodule (A)? If so, what exactly? If it's a device driver, it has 2 interfaces - "lower" that connects device via some physical interface and "upper" that provides API (/dev/device) to userspace; so which part is your focus? Or it's only about an internal logic of (A) and interfaces don't matter at all?

Comment: @KBart the goal was to use the same kmodule (A) but replace the real device by a software. So with your explaination I suppose I will have to modify the "lower" part of the kmodule to send simulated information to "upper"/dev/device. I think I will have to study more this part. Thanks.

Comment: @Fabien take a look at [LDD3](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3) - in case you haven't seen it before - it is one of the best starting points for Kernel device drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have to use scull driver for this type of application which helps to you and also saves your device and you need not have to connect your device and you are able to see all aspects and tests as you need in real device driver.